# Get directions childs tags AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i made this directive that i call in my html like

```
<my-datepicker />
```

what i want to do now, is to expend it, so that i can do something like this

```
<my-datepicker >
    <my-day>{{date}}</my-day>
    <my-month>{{moth}}</my-month>
    <my-year>{{year}}</my-year>
</my-datepicker>
```

resulting in my-datepicker directive can get the child elements.

how can you do this? do you need to make the childs like standanlone directive, an how can you get the value from them in the parent(my-datepicker) directive

Answer (score 0):

You can access parent directive controller like this:

```
app.directive('myDay', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^myDatepicker',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl) {
            parentCtrl.doSomething();
        }
    };
});
```

In parent:

```
app.directive('myDatepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function () {
            this.doSomething = function () {
                alert('Do something in parent');
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I think it's is what I'm looking for. i will report back after trying it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to extend your directive is by passing parameters (date month ec... ) as attributes.

Your html should be somethig like this

```
<my-datepicker day="day" month="month" year="year"/>
```

Inside your directive you should be able to retrieve those variables by declaring them in the scope.

```
function myDatepicker() {
var directive = {
    templateUrl: 'yourtemplate.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    link: link,
    scope: {
        date: '=',
        month: '=',
        year: '='
    }
}

return directive;

function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    // use here scope.date scope.month and scope.year
}
```

};

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i understand why you think that. but the reason i would like to do it the other way is because i'm going to do some html rendering and styling of those tags